# Month names in MySQL column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL column name called `fee`. Values inside `fee` are something like:
`Jan,Feb,Mar` or `Jan,Feb`

... which means the fee for Jan to March was paid (Jan to Feb was paid for the 2nd example).

How do I go about counting the number of months that those fees have been paid? ie. for the 1st example, I would expect to get 3 and 2 for the 2nd example.

Comment: you can split the string and count the number of items. However, I think a better design would be keeping track of the payment transactions in a separate table with foreign keys linking back to that table, and just querying the number of records associated with the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the months is always represented by 3 chars, maybe you can use

```
SELECT FLOOR((length(fee)+1)/4) FROM table_name;
```

we denote the number of months as *n*, notice that the number of commas is 1 less than *n*, because there isn't one at the end of the string. So the length of this field namely 'fee' can denote as 3*n + (n-1), denoted as *N*, so we can add 1 to *N* and divide by 4. The floor is round down to get the closest integer. Which can be removed in this case.

```
SELECT　length(fee)+1)/4 FROM table_name;
```

will get the right answer, the length() is a function returning the length of strings.

Comment: If your Month is always represented by 3 chars, for the number of commas is 1 less than the actual number of months

Comment: Yes it works ! Appreciate if you explain what you did. Am a bit new with this. Thanks .